# Multiple extrusion on selected curve objects using the Option (alt) key

Tags: shortcut

In Blender 2.80 I was able to extrude multiple curve objects, including text and imported SVG files by simply clicking and dragging on the Geometry Extrude field while pressing the Option (alt) key. That feature seems to be broken or removed in version 2.81. If I press the Option (alt) key then the field for the parameter freezes. Did they changed the way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer at the developer site. I had the **Emulate 3 Button Mouse** option checked. That changed the behavior of the Option (alt) key in combination with the left click button.